# Backpropagation in train and eval mode combined

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation

I am trying to backpropagate a network for a loss function defined as follows:
L = L_1 + L_2. Here L_1 is computed using dropout and batchnorm layers active where as L_2 is computed with dropout and batchnorm set to inactive. To update parameters gradients of L_1 and L_2 would have to be summed. I have written the following procedure, but don't know how to check for correctness. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
net.train()
...# Calculation of L_1...
L_1.backward()
net.eval()
...# Calculation of L_2...
L_2.backward()
net.train()
optimizer.step()
```

My understanding says that `L_1.backward()` will compute gradients of L_1 with respect to all parameters (including batchnorm), whereas `L_2.backward()` will compute gradients with respect to parameters only and add it to original gradients. Finally setting the network into train mode followed by `optimizer.step()`, updates all the parameters (including batchnorm).

Comment: Even in eval mode batch norm parameters alpha and gamma still have gradients updated. Eval mode changes how batch norm behaves and the running mean and std don't get updated. I wouldn't call this "inactive" though since batch norm in eval mode isn't a passthrough layer the way dropout is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood my mistake